# UITextField font size changes when start or stop entering the characters

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, fonts

I have seen many threads but not finding any concrete solution for this problem.

I have UITextfield created using XIB nothing has been done programmaticaly for that field.

As soon as i start typing, the font of textfield changes and once i move the focus out of it and as keyboard disappears the font size reduces.

how to disable this. I dont want the font to change when focus is moved out of textfield.

Comment: Yup! I was facing this issue. I tried many things, we are using some custom fonts which might be creating some problems. Because when i work out with sample project just having text field it was working fine. I can say this might be issue in setting custom fonts or may be it comes as by product of changes made in iOS TextKit..!

Answer (score 12):

Okie,

I guess I have found the solution.

Create a IBOutlet for the UITextfield.

in textFieldDidEndEditing and textFieldShouldReturn call below lines

```
[self.yourTextField setFont:nil];
[self.yourTextField setFont:"your font name and size"];
```

setting the font to nil is key without which new font will not be set

Comment: thanks this definitely worked for me. I noticed this is a bug, so the workaround is great. I think it has something to do with OTF files. You might want to try a TTF file to see if it does the same thing.